# Oracle 10g using regexp_replace on a CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, regexp-replace

I'd like to understand if it's possible via regular expression to extract a given attribute value in a stored Clob field.

Say I have the following data.

```
AttrName1+AttrVal1;
AttrName2+AttrVal2;
AttrName3+;
AttrName4+AttrVal4;
AttrName5+;
AttrName6+AttrVal7
```

Now in the select I'd like to check if AttrName2 has the value AttrVal2.

Note not all attribute names do have a value necessarily. See AttrName3, AttrName 5

Hope someone can enlighten me.

I know it's achievable via dbms.function (instr, substr, etc) but maybe there's a simpler way.

Comment: Are they different rows or stored together in CLOB?

Comment: Stored together in the same column/row

Comment: Have you tried using.  Like field1 like '%'||filedb|'%'

Comment: As I mentioned I need to query for Attribute values which are hardcoded in my example.

Comment: `SUBSTR` would do the job. you just need to cast it explicitly as VARCHAR2. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `SUBSTR` and `CASE` expression. However, since you have a CLOB data type, you need to explicitly CAST it as VARCHAR2 to compare.

Let's say your table looks like:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(str CLOB);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2  INTO t VALUES('A1+A1')
  3  INTO t VALUES('A2+B2')
  4  INTO t VALUES('A3+')
  5  INTO t VALUES('A4+A4')
  6  INTO t VALUES('A5+')
  7  INTO t VALUES('A6+B7')
  8  SELECT * FROM dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

STR
-----
A1+A1
A2+B2
A3+
A4+A4
A5+
A6+B7

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, you could do the comparison of the **CLOB** column as:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT str,
  3         CAST(SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '+', 1) -1) AS VARCHAR2(30)) attr1,
  4         CAST(SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '+', -1) +1) AS VARCHAR2(30)) attr2
  5  FROM t
  6  )
  7  SELECT str,
  8    attr1,
  9    attr2,
 10    CASE
 11      WHEN attr1 = attr2
 12      THEN 'Value matches'
 13      ELSE 'Not mathing'
 14    END val
 15  FROM DATA
 16  /

STR   ATTR1 ATTR2 VAL
----- ----- ----- -------------
A1+A1 A1    A1    Value matches
A2+B2 A2    B2    Not mathing
A3+   A3          Not mathing
A4+A4 A4    A4    Value matches
A5+   A5          Not mathing
A6+B7 A6    B7    Not mathing

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```